# Can't configure the rewrite log

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, apache2.4, rewritelog

I'd like to enable the rewrite log to debug some rewrite rules that are giving me problems. So I added these lines at the end of my **httpd.conf** file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteLog "/logs/rewrite.log"
   RewriteLogLevel 4
</IfModule>
```

Next thing I did was restart Apache. It causes an error however, and won't start. This is what I get in the XAMPP Control Panel:

```
13:14:56  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:14:56  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:14:56  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:14:56  [Apache]    Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
13:14:56  [Apache]    and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
```

I don't get any clue in **error.log** though. In fact no line is generated when this error occurs.

I also tried changing the RewriteLog line to use an absolute path:

```
RewriteLog "c:\xampp\apache\logs\rewrite.log"
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Which version of Apache?

In 2.4, RewriteLog* directives don't exist anymore as logging has been rewritten. In this case, you should append `mod_rewrite.c:trace3` to your `LogLevel` line where traceX is the level of verbosity (8 >= X >= 1). The output will be written to Apache standard error log (`ErrorLog`).

Could you also run these commands:
`httpd -t` (syntax checking) then `httpd -w` (run Apache but hold open the console, used as stderr)

Comment: Yes, my server is Apache 2.4. I've seen my default config is `LogLevel warn`, so should I do this?: `LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace3`

Comment: yes: with `LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace3` warn is the default verbosity level for all modules and you redefine mod_rewrite's level to a higher value

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you, it works! Just one more question: is it possible to create your own rewrite log apart from the error log in Apache 2.4?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This is a "side effect" of this new "way".

Comment: ok, no problem. For me it's enough to have it working. Thanks again and best regards! :)

Comment: Putting this line in `apache.conf` doesn't actually work, sadly.